# Can I do the Mann-Whitney test with different sample sizes 18 and 32?

Tags: sample-size, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

Can a Mann-Whitney test be done on different sample sizes, one sample about 18 and the other about 32? The problem is looking at the difference in views of tourists and locals about the environmental quality of a location.

Comment: Yes you can, a better question is what is your hypothesis?